# PHP mt_rand not returning an integer

Tags: php

I have the following code in a PHP script:

```
$sol = mt_rand(1,3);
```

I thought this was meant to return an integer but instead I'm getting a number with about 6 decimal places. How can I force it to return 1,2 or 3?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, it is returning only integers over here.  Which PHP version?

Comment: The definition for that function states it returns type int, no cause for changes.  Is it overridden somehow? (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

Comment: My fault, I was echoing a different variable to my random one. Sorry for wasting your time. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ceiling or floor functions to round to an integer.

```
$sol = floor(mt_rand(1, 3));
$sol = ceil(mt_rand(1, 3));
```

Comment: that still doesn't return integers!

Comment: @Sam please provide the complete code you are using, the platform, and an example of your output.